# Simple form collection using Asp.Net c# - entityframe work

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, entity-framework

I've got a simple form with 3 text boxes and and a button. All I want to do is send the data in the form to my database. In my database I have a table called contacts with three columns (ID-Primary Key,fname,lname,phone) I've created an Ado.net Entity framework model and called it Contacts.

This is the code I've got so far:

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Contact con = new Contact();
    con.fname = TextBox1.Text;
    con.sname = TextBox2.Text;
    con.phone = TextBox3.ToString();

    ContactDb db = new ContactDb();
    db.Contacts.Add(con);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I click ok this error comes up:Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Answer (score 0):

EntityValidationErrors occurs usually when we pass NULL value for required fields.

Try passing Primary key ID value as  0 and check.

also you can check which field is causing issue, using this catch statement,

refer Richard answer in this post.  [EF Code First: How do I see 'EntityValidationErrors' property from the nuget package console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219864/ef-code-first-how-do-i-see-entityvalidationerrors-property-from-the-nuget-pac)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `con.phone = TextBox3.ToString();` should be `TextBox3.Text;`

You may have some validation attributed on your `ContactDb` class that may be worth posting for us to look at as well.

Comment: How do I check if validation has been attributed? Thanks Dan

Comment: Whoops, meant attributeS.  Find the class implementation of ContactDb and update your post with it.  If it's big, just include the implementations of the `fname`, `sname`, and `phone` properties.