# Asp.net MVC UserManager Update

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, usermanager

I have tried to update user data in database, I am taking value from view and I assign these data to current user.Yet, I am taking an error in that line when I update user's data `var result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(userAccount);`.It is written **Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.** .How can I fix that? Thanks

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ModifyAccount(ModifyUserAccountViewModel model)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(int.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId()));
        UserAccount userAccount = (UserAccount)user;
        userAccount.surname = model.surname;
        userAccount.name = model.name;
        userAccount.Email = model.email;
        var result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(userAccount);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = "Account modyfyied successfully!" });
        }
        AddErrors(result);
        return View("Error");
     }
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);          
    }
```

Comment: Did you: See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details? Can you determine what validation errors you get?

Comment: **System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException**, it is written

Comment: You can try using this code to determine what property causes yours error: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6258174/1081079

Comment: **An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_2cj5f1rz.dll but was not handled in user code
** I am taking that error now

Comment: Can you post your changed code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try, as suggested by @Praveen Prasad in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6258174/1081079) post, to catch the exception to see what validation errors you have:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public async Task<ActionResult> ModifyAccount(ModifyUserAccountViewModel model)
 {
    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(int.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId()));
    UserAccount userAccount = (UserAccount)user;
    userAccount.surname = model.surname;
    userAccount.name = model.name;
    userAccount.Email = model.email;

    try { 
      var result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(userAccount);
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
    {
        foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
            {
               Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", 
                                validationError.PropertyName, 
                                validationError.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    }

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
       return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = "Account modyfyied successfully!" });
    }
    AddErrors(result);
    return View("Error");
}
```