# EntityFrameWork Add function: Unable to load the specified metadata resource

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am using Sql server 2014 and made a ADO.NET Entity Data Model. It generated this model:
[image]

I am trying to add mails I retrieve into my database. It looks like this:

```
    public int StoreMail(PhishingMail PhishingMail)
    {
        using (var phishingMailStorage = new PhishFinderDB2Entities2())
        {
          //  phishingMailStorage.Database.Connection.Open();

            phishingMailStorage.PhishingMail.Add(PhishingMail);
            phishingMailStorage.SaveChanges();
        }
        return PhishingMail.PhishingMailId;
    }
```

Whenever I debug the program. I am stuck at this part:

```
phishingMailStorage.PhishingMail.Add(PhishingMail);
```

> It gives me the metadataexception was unhandeld exception:An unhandled
>   exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' occurred
>   in EntityFramework.dll Additional information: Unable to load the
>   specified metadata resource.

This is my connection string:
I really don't know why it generated this gigantic string. It may cause the problem.

```
<add name="PhishFinderDB2Entities2" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataAccess.PhishFinderModel.csdl|res://*/DataAccess.PhishFinderModel.ssdl|res://*/DataAccess.PhishFinderModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=WIN7DEV;initial catalog=PhishFinderDB;integrated security=True;pooling=False;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /><add name="PhishFinderDB2Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataAccess.PhishFinderModel.csdl|res://*/DataAccess.PhishFinderModel.ssdl|res://*/DataAccess.PhishFinderModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local);initial catalog=PhishFinderDB2;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /><add name="PhishFinderDB2" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataAccess.Model1.csdl|res://*/DataAccess.Model1.ssdl|res://*/DataAccess.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=WPNLL0038874\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=PhishFinderDB2;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

Do you know why I get this exception?
Thanks

Comment: can this be that your PhishingMail class is static and the parameter PhishingMail is confused with your class name? Maybe it's not the reason - but you should keep your parameters lower case in any case in line with convention e.g. public int StoreMail(PhishingMail phishingMail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete the generated `PhishFinderDB2.edmx` (keep in mind to save data, if you made your own adjustments).
Delete also the connectionstring.
Then regenerate the whole PhishFinderDB2 ado.net model. 
For me this helped multiple times.

Comment: that helped a bit But now i get this error at the savechanges method: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Comment: In 'public int StoreMail(PhishingMail PhishingMail)' you use the Variable in the syntax of an 'PhinshingMail-Object', you wrote it both exact the same way. Maybe you should rename to 'public int StoreMail(PhishingMail phishingMail)'. I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, I changed that. I still get the same exception. But aleast I am one step further.

Comment: Hmm, what i would do is comparing your values of the object with the DB-Values, if all constraint are set properly in code.

Comment: I just found out, that you can debug all these Exceptions. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400530/validation-failed-for-one-or-more-entities-while-saving-changes-to-sql-server-da
or:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795300/validation-failed-for-one-or-more-entities-see-entityvalidationerrors-propert